# JQuery Date Picker issue inside Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker

i am using this Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(addDataPicker);  for my script to load on every post back for JQuery Datepicker. Because i am using updatepanel. Its working fine in second postback.but its not working the first time of page load. Please Help me out

Answer (score 0):

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(addDataPicker) event is raised after an asynchronous postback is finished and control has been returned to the browser.So your addDataPicker is added after postback is done, you need to add this after document is loaded, i.e. if you are using Jquery this can be done by,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your datepicker init function here.
   });
```

Hope this will help.